# WebAPI project not accepting ImageResizer config

Tags: visual-studio-2012, imageresizer

I've created a small WebAPI that uses ImageResizer to scale some images stored in my machine. It works flawlessly.

Now I need to use the RemoteReader plugin to allow for on-the-fly resizing of web-served images. I've installed `ImageResizer.Plugins.RemoteReader` using nuget but all the requests fail because IIS Web Core won't accept the `resizer` tag in the `web.config` file, giving a 0x80070032 error code. I've tried an empty `<resizer />` tag and it still fails.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012, the project is .Net framework 4.0 and both ImageResizer and ImageResizer.Plugins.RemoteReader are version="3.4.2".

Anyone has any clue as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't install ImageResizer itself into Web.config, so the `<resizer/>` element hasn't been defined. Install `ImageResizer.MvcWebConfig` and you'll be good to go.